# How to incorporate multiple parameters into WHERE with python MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, parameters, mysql-python

I have a program where I am trying to match users based on some parameters. I am having an issue with trying to filter a selection of data from my database based on two parameters. I am using visual studio code and mysql-connector/mysql-connector-python.
Here is what my database looks like:

```
[('Addie', 'English', 'Green', 'Music', 12), 
('Jim', 'Spanish', 'Green', 'Music', 14), 
('Bob', 'English', 'Blue', 'Music', 14), 
('Phil', 'Spanish', 'Green', 'Music', 14)]
```

The following is my code

This part of the code works fine. It gets the age (element) in the list of ages, which is related to something else in my code that isn't really important to the issue. The code gets all of the information when age is a specific value. You could replace the %s with 14 to be more specific to the database.

```
    for elem in res:
        sqll = "SELECT * FROM ultra WHERE age=%s"
        mycursor.execute(sqll, elem)
        myresults = mycursor.fetchall()
```

The next part of the code checks to see if the length of the results is bigger than 1, meaning that there are multiple results (thus multiple matches). If there are, a list of languages is created based on what languages are spoken by the user. Then, the program determines which languages have multiples and makes a list of them.

```
        if len(myresults) > 1:
            lang_list = []
            for result in myresults:
              lang_list.append(result[1])
            print(lang_list)
            lang_res = []
            for language in lang_list:
                x = lang_list.count(language)
```

So, here's where I'm having an issue. I'm attempting to select all of the data from the table (which is ultra, by the way) with the two parameters of age being equal to the already created elem above, and language being equal to the language in the lang_list. If I print out both of these values, age = (14, ) and language = Spanish. So, theoretically I should be able to filter the data this way but nothing is returned in lang_results

```
                if x > 1:
                    lang_res.append(language)
                    sqll_l = "SELECT * FROM ultra WHERE age = %s and language = '%d'"
                    lang_tup = (language, )
                    mycursor.execute(sqll_l, elem, lang_tup)
                    lang_results = mycursor.fetchall()
                    print(lang_results)
                else:
                    lang_list.remove(language)
```

I appreciate you taking the time to read through this. If you have any idea what could be causing lang_results to be blank, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: First, it should be `...age = %d and language = %s`.  Age is a number, language is a string.  Second, you should have `lang_tup = (elem, language)` and `mycursor.execute(sqll_l, lang_tup)`.  See if that does better.

Comment: Step 1. in debugging this sort of issue is to print out the query that is getting sent to the database,  run it manually and see if it gives you anything.

Comment: `lang_list = [ result[1] for result in myresults]`, you are modiving the iterable you are iterating over `lang_list`, you are processing the same language multiple times

Comment: @TimRoberts for DB-API parameter substitution, _all_ placeholders should be `%s`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I get the error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type" when I do that.

Comment: @JeffUK running it manually in MySQL workbench works perfectly

Comment: That's the problem with showing snippets of code instead of a complete sample.  If `elem` is a tuple, the you need `lang_tup = (elem[0], language)`.